# how can create new array in main array in react js ,javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In that image i can explain what is my question

[image]
[image]

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react'


function App() {
  const [head,setHead] = useState([])
  const [tail,setTail] = useState([])

  const main = [];
  main.push(head,tail)
console.log(main);
  const handleHead = () =>{
    const HeadButton = 'H'
    setHead([...head,HeadButton])
  }

  const handleTail = () =>{
    const TailButton = 'T'
    setTail([...tail,TailButton])
  }




  return (
    <div className="App">`your text`
      <button onClick={(e)=>handleHead(e)} >Head</button>
      <button onClick={(e)=>handleTail(e)}>Tail</button>
      <h1>{head.join(',')}</h1>
      <h1>{tail.join(',')}</h1>

 </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i can 2 array inside of main array than how can create a third array inside of main array in react js

Comment: You need a array in between head array and tail array, right? Can you try to implement linkedlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [FinalList, setFinalList] = useState([]);
  const [ConsecutiveHead, setConsecutiveHead] = useState(false);
  const [ConsecutiveTail, setConsecutiveTail] = useState(false);
 
  const handleHead = () =>{
  if(ConsecutiveHead) {
    const list = [...FinalList];
    
    list[list.length -1].push("head");
    setFinalList(list);
  } else {
    setFinalList(prev => [...prev, ["head"]]);
  }
  setConsecutiveHead(true);
  setConsecutiveTail(false);
  }

  const handleTail = () =>{
  if(ConsecutiveTail) {
    const list = [...FinalList];
    list[list.length -1].push("tail");
    setFinalList(list);
  } else {
    setFinalList(prev => [...prev, ["tail"]]);
  }
  setConsecutiveHead(false);
  setConsecutiveTail(true);
  }
console.log(FinalList)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(e)=>handleHead(e)} >Head</button>
      <button onClick={(e)=>handleTail(e)}>Tail</button>
 </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```